# C++ No instance of function template matches speciefied type

Tags: c++, templates

I have template:

```
template <typename T>
T func(const T[],int);
```

and I try specialize it to:

`template <> char* func(const char[], int);`

but I have an Error:

> No instance of function template "func" matches specified type

I don't know why I cannot return char* with this template? Is the only solution is change to:

```
template <typename T>
T* func(const T[],int);
```

Comment: Yes, you seem to have solved your problem already. Your original template function can only return a `T`, not a `T *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring your specialization wrong:

```
template <>
char func<char>(const char[], int)
```

If you are meaning to return a pointer, you have solved it on your own, and need to change the general case to a `T*`

`T` refers to just a `typename`, not including qualifiers - your function could also return `T &` if you wanted it to. `T` is just the type/name (`typename`!) of the object.